# Import tesseract error

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm trying to import tesseract in Python with a Mac Maverick, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tesseract.py", line 26, in <module>
    _tesseract = swig_import_helper()
  File "tesseract.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    import _tesseract
ImportError: No module named _tesseract
```

I followed these steps to install tesseract:
https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompilePythonTesseractForMacMountainLion

What should i do to fix this?

UPDATE:

Traceback of python setup.py build

```
os=darwin
Current Version : tesseract
~~~cv_pc~~~
{'extra_link_args': ['not', 'found', 'sh:', 'command', 'pkg-config:']}
['extra_link_args']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 160, in <module>
    libname="open"+item.split("libopen")[1].split(".")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

UPDATE 2 homwbrew version:

Message for python setup.py install --user

os=darwin
Current Version : tesseract
~~~cv_pc~~~
{'extra_link_args': ['No', 'Perhaps', 'variable', 'in', 'containing', 'to', 'not', 'should', 'environment', 'opencv', 'add', 'you', "`opencv.pc'", 'Package', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH', 'search', 'package', 'was', "'opencv'", 'directory', 'found', 'the', 'path.', 'pkg-config']}
['extra_link_args']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 160, in 
    libname="open"+item.split("libopen")[1].split(".")[0]

### IndexError: list index out of range

UPDATE 3 : from steps 1-3 all works great.
But at step 4, i get stuck at
python setup.py clean

which prints this message:

```
os=darwin
Current Version : tesseract
~~~cv_pc~~~
{'extra_link_args': ['/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_features2d.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_objdetect.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_video.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_imgproc.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_ocl.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_superres.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_nonfree.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_legacy.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_core.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_gpu.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_ts.a', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_videostab.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_ml.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_stitching.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/libopencv_photo.dylib'], 'include_dirs': ['/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/include/opencv', '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/include']}
['extra_link_args', 'include_dirs']
add lib: opencv_features2d
add lib: opencv_objdetect
add lib: opencv_video
add lib: opencv_imgproc
add lib: opencv_ocl
add lib: opencv_contrib
add lib: opencv_superres
add lib: opencv_nonfree
add lib: opencv_flann
add lib: opencv_legacy
add lib: opencv_core
add lib: opencv_gpu
add lib: opencv_ts
add lib: opencv_videostab
add lib: opencv_highgui
add lib: opencv_ml
add lib: opencv_stitching
add lib: opencv_calib3d
add lib: opencv_photo
===========['stdc++', 'tesseract', 'lept', 'opencv_features2d', 'opencv_objdetect', 'opencv_video', 'opencv_imgproc', 'opencv_ocl', 'opencv_contrib', 'opencv_superres', 'opencv_nonfree', 'opencv_flann', 'opencv_legacy', 'opencv_core', 'opencv_gpu', 'opencv_ts', 'opencv_videostab', 'opencv_highgui', 'opencv_ml', 'opencv_stitching', 'opencv_calib3d', 'opencv_photo']===========
['.', '/usr/local/include/opencv2', '/usr/local/include/opencv']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 251, in <module>
    swig_opts=["-c++", "-I"+inclpath('tesseract'),
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: How do you install tesseract?

Comment: Modules starting with underscore are by convention compiled (C) modules. Swig is an automatic wrapper to produce such a module from a C library. It would be interesting to have the log of the setup.py build because it seems the module do not get compiled properly.

Comment: Those docs show two ways of the doing the last (and most important) step: untar-ing a pre-built binary, or building normally with `setup.py`. Which one did you do?

Comment: Also, have you installed any additional versions of Python 2.7 beyond the one that came with OS X (/usr/bin/python), like a MacPorts version (/opt/local/bin/python) or a python.org version (/usr/local/bin/python)?

Comment: From your update… if `python setup.py build` failed, then you haven't actually installed it. I'm not sure how you ended up with `tesseract.py` on your `sys.path` in that case; maybe you're running out of the tesseract source directory? But it doesn't really matter; until you can actually get it installed, you can't use it.

Comment: Already updated my question with traceback of setup.py build. @abarnert I tried with both methods.

Comment: One last thing: those instructions explicitly have you build it for the MacPorts Python 2.7. Is that the one that's actually the first `python` on your path? In particular, what does `which python` say?

Comment: OK, since you tried it both ways… it's quite possible that the `sudo tar zxvf python-tesseract.macosx-10.8-intel.tar.gz -C /opt/local` did the wrong thing because it's a binary specifically for 10.8 and you're using it on 10.9. Maybe that's how you ended up with a half-installed copied?

Comment: One more one last thing: at the top of the page you linked, it explicitly says "obsolete now !! use homebrew version pls Compile for HomeBrew". And these obsolete instructions haven't been updated since months before 10.9 came out, while the Homebrew ones were updated a couple weeks ago.

Comment: OK, to be clear: Steps 1-3 all worked, step 4 you chose the first version, and you also did a new `svn checkout` and everything rather than trying to reuse the one with a left-over broken build. Right?

Comment: Yes, step 1-3 all ok- I redid all once again. In step 4, I'm stuck at setup.py clean

Comment: You didn't answer the part about whether you did a clean `svn checkout` into a brand-new directory, or tried to reuse the same directory from last time that has a left-over broken build in it. The fact that `setup.py clean` failed strongly implies the latter. In which case… don't do that. And more generally, if you want someone to help you, you have to actually do what they tell you to do, instead of something different, not mentioning what part you did differently, and then asking why that different thing didn't work.

Comment: OK, your latest update shows a complete different error than the one you posted an hour ago, despite you claiming to have done the same steps. Does that mean you didn't actually do those steps an hour ago, but did now? Or that you did a different set of steps this time? Or what?

Comment: I improved on the first steps. I installed opencv correctly this time. But now, i'm now longer using macports, just homebrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't import it successfully is that you never installed it successfully.

Your output from `setup.py` shows this: it's failing with an exception.

So, why were you able to `import tesseract` and get far enough for code in `tesseract.py` to fail, instead of not even being able to find it? My guess is that you started Python with your current working directory in the middle of the tesseract source tree, so the source-code copy of `tesseract.py` was found, even though nothing is installed. But it's also certainly possible that you have an incomplete, broken install, especially since you tried untarring a binary copy for the wrong version of OS X before trying to install via `setup.py`.

Anyway, what you want to know is how to fix it, not why it isn't working, right?

Well, right at the very top of the [instructions you linked](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompilePythonTesseractForMacMountainLion), it says:

> obsolete now !! use homebrew version pls Compile for HomeBrew

The fact that the instructions you're following weren't updated for Mavericks, and link to a binary package made specifically for 10.8 only (and possibly for older MacPorts code as well) is a good sign that they really mean it when they say "obsolete", two exclamation points and everything.

Before you follow the Homebrew instructions, unless you have some other need for MacPorts, I would suggest uninstalling MacPorts completely. You can usually do this with just `sudo rm -rf /opt/local`, then editing your `~/.bash_profile` to remove all references to `/opt/local`, but you may want to check for the latest instructions on the MacPorts site first. If you're afraid of doing this, you can always just `sudo mv /opt/local /opt/local-bak`, which will leave it there, but out of the way.

Also, do not use your existing checkout of the source code. It's got a broken, incomplete build in it, and who knows how that will affect any attempt to build it again. Just remove that directory entirely, and when you get to the `svn checkout` step of the instructions, you'll get a brand new, clean copy.

And then, just start at the top of the [How to compile python-tesseract for Homebrew(Mac Mountain Lion/Maverick)](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompilePythonTesseractForHomebrewMacMountainLion) page.

When you get to step 4, don't do both steps, just do one or the other. I'd suggest the first version, building from source, because it will probably be more obvious, and easier to recover from, if anything goes wrong. But if you do the second version, installing the binary, make sure to get the 10.9 version this time, not the 10.8.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed macports, and followed all the steps again, but still not working.

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano: You mean you followed all the obsolete MacPorts steps again and got the same error? In that case, I'm not surprised. If you mean you followed all the new Homebrew steps, we need the same details for your new attempt as you gave for your old attempt—which variation you attempted, what went wrong, where, with logs, etc.

Comment: I updated my question with responses from homebrew trial

Comment: From steps 1-3, all fine. But at step 4, I get stucked at setup.py clean

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem.  The only issue was that I had to run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Running tesseract -v from the command line confirms whether this is an issue.