# Compiling python tesseract for OS X 10.9

Tags: python, pip, osx-mavericks, homebrew, tesseract

I'm trying to compile tesseract following this [installation guide](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompilePythonTesseractForHomebrewMacMountainLion) which uses homebrew. I get to the line:

> setup.py clean

Then get this output and error:

```
os=darwin
Current Version : tesseract
~~~cv_pc~~~
{'extra_link_args': ['not', 'found', 'sh:', 'command', 'pkg-config:']}
['extra_link_args']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 160, in <module>
    libname="open"+item.split("libopen")[1].split(".")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages in the guide a number of times and keep coming back to this error.

I've looked at this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054818/import-tesseract-error) but have been unable to apply the fix to my problem.

I would like to understand what this error means so I can have some insight into fixing it the next time. I also want to successfully install tesseract.

More information:

- 'which python' is '/usr/local/bin/python'
- I just updated to OS X 10.9 because I was getting 'Segmentation fault: 11' when running Python in OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled homebrew and all the brews I had previously installed with it. I followed the instructions on the installation guide and successfully installed tesseract. The error was in regards to installing cv2, which was apparently not installed properly. However, this once again leaves me with a Segmentation fault: 11, although the problem asked is resolved.